# What Can Be The Cause Of Low Voltage After Resoldering?

Tags: power, voltage, soldering, wiring, flux

I had to resolder mosquito zapper's black and red wires back after **zapper fell on the floor** and black wire detached and later red wire detached when i was trying to solder black wire back. After resoldering wires, the zapper no longer produced sparks as it did previously and its electricity did not kick away mosquitoes at all anymore. Can it be that i used wrong material for resoldering? It was solder of 67/33 i think from China with 2% flux:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here are 3 new close-up pictures where you can see in better details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possibly a cold or otherwise bad solder joint.

Comment: This is for sure NOT caused by bad/wrong soldering material.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller Why nothing? I was referred to ask such question here.

Comment: Why did you have to resolder it? What have you resoldered?

Comment: @LeonHeller: Since when does every question on this site have to be related to the *design* of electronic systems? Last I checked, the title of the site is "Electrical Engineering", not "Electronic Design".

Comment: Clabacchio got the point! What is the reason of resoldering? What problem was there before? How can you be sure that the current problem is caused by resoldering?

Comment: See the FAQ, it states electronic design. This question isn't about EE, either.

Comment: @clabacchio Updated my question.

Comment: @AlKepp Updated my question.

Comment: Do you have a cheap VOM meter? Try probing to see if the circuit is getting power. Perhaps the switch broke when it fell?

Comment: @JonnyBoats What is VOM meter? I only have cheap multimeter...

Comment: @Boris VOM stands for Volt Ohm Multimeter - same as multimeter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter

Comment: @JonnyBoats But it might fry multimeter.

Comment: @Boris you can take the batteries out and check conductivity of the wires and switch. Without batteries nothing should get fried.

Comment: @JonnyBoats How is it possible to test resistance without batteries?

Comment: @Boris I meant take the batteries out of the Zapper. You will need to leave the batteries in the multimeter.

Comment: @JonnyBoats I meant batteries in Zapper, not in multimeter. Without electricity there would be nothing to resist.

Comment: @Boris I you have a question on how to use your multimeter to measure resistance, you should really ask that as a new question, or check the manual that came with the meter.

Answer (score 1):

I would look over the board carefully by eye, and with a continuity tester. Look for a crack in the board or in a solder joint. If you find a crack in a joint, reflow that solder. If you find a crack in the board, bridge it with solder or a wire.

Comment: But since there is voltage multiplier will it burn multimeter? Zapper reduces voltage and increases current, people say so grill kicks away mosquitos.

Comment: The circuit will be powered off while you are testing it.